# Suppress keydown where there is a confirm() box before return false;

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events, keydown, onkeydown

I have a massive Javascript file capturing various keydowns on various screens of an application. I always use `return false();` to prevent the default keydown action from occurring, which works great.

However, on this particular keydown, there is a `confirm()` box before the `return false;`. If I hit <kbd>C</kbd>, the `confirm()` dialogue comes up. If I move that out of the way, underneath it, the `c` has already been written to the text box.

How can I successfully suppress the `keydown`? This is only required to work in Chrome.

```
document.onkeydown = keyDown;

function keyDown()
{
    switch(window.event.keyCode)
    {
        case(67):
            if(confirm('You have unsaved data! Press OK to Save or Cancel to Discard')) {
                alert('Do something...');
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
            window.location = '/invoice-12345';
            return false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @MitjaFelicijan Same problem. I also tried `onkeypress` but it doesn't handle it at all then.

Comment: Where exactly do you have the code that writes to text box?

Comment: @MitjaFelicijan There is no code to write to a text box. The code in my OP is enough.

Comment: You could also try using `event.preventDefault();` at the start of your code block.

Comment: @Shmiddty This seems to have no effect. I put it directly after `case(67):` - correct me if you manage to get it working; this would be a much more elegant solution.

Comment: It would work if you separate your logic a little bit. Use `keyDown` to suppress characters from being typed, and use `keyUp` to trigger actions based on the key pressed. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/fmDDv/1/

Comment: @Shmiddty I accept that's a good solution, however this code is actually part of a much larger section to control key presses for a lot of different screens of an application. This switch is around 500 lines long (not counting the functions the keydowns call), so I don't particularly feel like doubling that :p Also, not all keys are canceled - e.g. when in an <input> box; so I can't do a catch-all on the keydown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delay the confirm using `setTimeout`.

```
document.onkeydown = keyDown;

function keyDown()
{
    switch(window.event.keyCode)
    {
        case(67):
            setTimeout(function() {
                if(confirm('You have unsaved data! Press OK to Save or Cancel to Discard')) {
                    alert('Do something...');
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
                window.location = '/invoice-12345';
            }, 0);
            return false;
        break;
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q4gqU/)